# Unable to bring Game State back to menu

Tags: python, menu, pygame

I'm creating a small game using Python with the module Pygame.

I tried implementing a pretty basic (and I guess a pretty naive) state manager.

**However,

I currently have an issue :

once I switch the the "play" state, I can't switch back to the "menu".

Is this a flaw in how I designed my state manager?**

I have two methods,

1. The `state_change` method takes one argument, the desired state.
2. The `state_check` method takes a state as the only argument and returns it as the current state.

Here are the two methods:

```py
def state_check(self, state):
    self.current_state = state
    print self.current_state
    return self.current_state

def state_change(self, state):
    self.state = state
```

Before the main loop,
The first `state` is initialized to be "menu".
Inside the main loop,
`state_check` is before the if-statements to indicate which state the start with.

```py
def game_loop(self):                                                                       

    running = True
    self.test_car = car()
    self.state = "menu"
    while running:
        pygame.display.set_caption("Project G")
        self.state_check(self.state)
        if self.current_state ==  "menu":
            self.state_check(self.state)
            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))
            #Blits the current state on the screen for testing purposes.
            self.screen.blit(self.menu_text, (700, 580))
            self.event_handler()
            pygame.display.flip()
        if self.current_state == "play":
            self.state_check(self.state)
            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))
            #Blits the current state on the screen.
            self.screen.blit(self.play_text, (700, 580))
            self.test_car.event_handler()
            self.test_car.update(self.test_car.x_speed, self.test_car.y_speed)
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Within the if-statements,
Are the event handler methods, which I've currently made to take keyboard inputs to switch between states (By calling the `state_change` method) and to quit the program.

Using some print methods, I've **ruled out the possibility of the keys not registering**.

```py
#Event handler for the menu

def event_handler(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_p:
                self.state_change("play")
                print "Key Pressed: p"
            if event.key == K_q:
                print "Key Pressed: q"
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

```py
#Sample of the Event handler for "play"

def event_handler(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_m:
                self.state_change("menu")
                print "Key Pressed: m"
            if event.key == K_q:
                print "Key Pressed: q"
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things a little - do you really need check_state and set_state functions, and two variables?

I would do something like this:

```
class State(object):
    menu = "menu"
    play = "play"

class Game(??):

    def event_handler(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_m:
                    self.state = State.menu
                    print "Key Pressed: m"
                elif event.key == K_p:
                    self.state = State.play
                    print "Key Pressed: p"

    def game_loop(self):
        self.state = State.menu

        while running:
            if self.state is State.menu:
                # Do menu things
            elif self.state is State.play:
                # Play game!
```

Answer (score 1):

A few possiblities, the following line might be referring to the wrong object (`test_car` when it's supposed to be the menu?) , but I can't really tell without the rest of the code.

```
self.test_car.event_handler()
```

But if that's supposed to happen, then within that `test_car.event_handler` you're calling `self.state_change` which might not change the state of what you're expecting, because by then, `self` is the `test_car` and not actually the menu. That means that you never actually change `menu.state` (or whatever object `main_loop`is running in) and instead are changing `test_car.state`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two **if** statements one after the other in the running loop.  Try using an **if** and **elif** statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have complicated your game state management.

1. There is no need of the functions,

   - `state_change`
   - `state_check`.
2. Or the 2 variables for handling the state.

   - `self.state`
   - `self.current_state`

For game state, you could have used a variable
 -  `<type 'bool'>` if there are 2.
 -  `<type 'int'>` if there are more than 2.
   But then using a string make the code readable.

In this case,**even 1 variable will do**,(see below)
I **recommend on using 2 variables**
1. A `tuple` containing all possible states.
2. Current state, value or index (in reference to the `tuple`)

This approach also will work with many more states, giving you scope for developing more states, without much management hastles,

How?
Look at the code below and the use of the 2 variables

1. `self.state`
2. `self.states`

**Code:**

```
class Game:

    def __init__(...):
        self.states = ('menu','play')
        self.state = 0

    def events_play(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # event handling
                self.state = self.states[0]

    def events_menu(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # event handling
                self.state = self.states[1]

    def game_loop(self):

        while running:
            if self.state == 'menu':
                # I always handle events first :)
                self.events_menu()
                # Do menu things

            elif self.state == 'play':
                # I always handle events first :)
                self.events_play()
                # Play game!
```